# Set Default Radio Button + Associated Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am creating a widget that utilizes stylized radios and divs to display different bits of data, based on quotes for precious metal commodities. I need the radio "current" to load by default when the page loads. Using `checked="checked"`does check enable the radio (by underlining the label), but it doesn't load the associated div. I need the div to load on default too.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {
 $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
        $('.toHide').hide();
        $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show(100);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="title">
    <text id="titletext">Commodities</text>
</div>
<div id="titleaccent">
</div>
<!--The form for the radio toggle buttons-->
<form name="range">
<input id="rdb1" class="radio" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" >
<label for="rdb1">Current</label>
<input id="rdb2" class="radio" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" >
<label for="rdb2">24-Hour</label>
<input id="rdb3" class="radio" type="radio" name="toggler" value="3" >
<label for="rdb3">Week</label>
<input id="rdb4" class="radio" type="radio" name="toggler" value="4" >
<label for="rdb4">Month</label>
</form>

<!--The div and associated data for each radio toggle button-->
<div id="blk-1" class="toHide" style="display:none">
Current commodity quote info here
</div>
<div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">
24-hour comparison of commodity quote info here
</div>
<div id="blk-3" class="toHide" style="display:none">
Weekly comparison of commodity quote info here
</div>
<div id="blk-4" class="toHide" style="display:none">
Monthly comparison of commodity quote info here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#title{
background-color: #103346;
height: 28px;
width: 305px;
}

#titletext{
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 15pt;
position: fixed;
    top: 11px;
    left: 18px;
}

#titleaccent{
background-color: #C3A43F;
height:  6px;
width: 305px;
}

.radio{
display: none;
margin: 10px;
}

.radio + label{
display:inline-block;
margin:-2px;
padding: 4px 12px;
}

.radio:checked + label{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Rest assured, working on it. It's a CSS and JS issue. Gimme a sec.

Comment: I understand Derek. Thank you for publicizing my immediate deletion of retardation lol.

Comment: @NicholasHazel - You know people with 10K+ rep can still see your deleted post right? ;)

Comment: To expand my knowledge, understanding, troubleshooting, etc, I've decided to come onto Stack Overflow and give back all the help that was given. New to SO as far as answering questions, and getting into the feel of it, but thank you for your tip. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use some `CSS` and `JS`:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/cW4DR/1/

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
        $('.toHide').hide();
        $('.current').hide();
        $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show(100);
    });
});
```

---

```
.toHide{
    display:none;
}
.current{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
<input type="radio" name="toggler" ... checked>

$(function(){
    var whatever = function(){
        $('.toHide').hide();
        $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show(100);
    };
    $("[name=toggler]").click(whatever);
    $("[name=toggler]:checked").each(whatever);
});
```